# jQuery on click is not being fired

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have UL like this:

```
<ul class="term-list">
    <li class="term-item firstItem" ><a href="/stuff/?filter_for=1">Filter for 1</a> <span class="count">(20)</span></li>
    <li class="term-item toggleable " style="display: none;"><a href="/stuff/?filter_for=2">Filter for 2</a> <span class="count">(16)</span></li>
    <li class="term-item toggleable " style="display: none;"><a href="/stuff/?filter_for=3">Filter for 3</a> <span class="count">(11)</span></li>
    <li class="term-item toggleable " style="display: none;"><a href="/stuff/?filter_for=4"> <span class="count">(7)</span></li>
    <li class="more lastItem">More...</li>
</ul>
```

I want to capture a click on the last element "more". What I have and what works for other is this:

```
$("ul.term-list li.more").click(function(){
    alert("hello");
});
```

I am sure that jQuery is loaded as trying to alert in any other place works just fine.

Any help or guidance is much appreciated.

Comment: Your class is `term-list` while your selector is `term_list`. Is it a typo?

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev: thats what it is...

Comment: @Domas it's selector mistake

Comment: I have just chnged the selector to "term-list", but it still wouldn't work

Answer (score 1):

your class name was wrong

Check your spelling in class name given in Javascript.

```
$("ul.term-list li.more").click(function(){
    alert("hello");
});
```

**EDIT**

Here its the working [FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/v4vishnuprasad/Lucdd/1/)

Comment: Just changed that, but it stil wouldn't print out the alert

Comment: The problem was the $ sign instead of jQuery. I have answered the question for somebody in the future.

Comment: Yes.. its good.. its because of jQuery conflicts. Keeep doing.. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul class="term-list">
```

and the first part of your selector

```
$("ul.term_list li.more")
```

won't match. Simple as that. *term-list* doesn't equal *term_list*.

Comment: Just changed that, but it stil wouldn't print out the alert

Answer (score 0):

May be helpful for other in future:

This piece of jQuery code was enqued in Wordpress page and therefore wouldn't run. I have to replace every `$` with `jQuery`and it now runs.